# Connected Component using dfs in matlab not working

Tags: matlab, image-processing, recursion, depth-first-search

I want to detect the connected components in a supplied binary (black and white) image. I am using DFS to do it. But it is falling in a infinite loops. I know that by default matlab do not support recursion beyond 500 depth. So for safety i am using a small image of size only 100 X 200. However following is my code. Can any body please help me detect the problem ?

Calling code :

```
img = imread('small_img.png');

[row col] = size(img);

img_label = zeros(row,col,'uint8');

labelCounter = 1;

for i=1:row
   for j=1:col
     if img(i,j)==0 && img_label(i,j)==0
         dfs(i,j,img,img_label,row,col,labelCounter);
     end
   end
end

imshow(img);
```

and the dfs

```
function dfs(i,j,img,img_label,row,col,labelCounter)
    if i < 1 || i >row || j < 1 || j > col || img_label(i,j) ~=0 || img(i,j) ~=0
       return; 
    end
    img_label(i,j) = labelCounter;

    dfs(i,j-1,img,img_label,row,col,labelCounter);
    dfs(i-1,j,img,img_label,row,col,labelCounter);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function dfs does not return `img_label`. In the first call of dfs, one pixel in `img_label` will be set to `labelCounter`. In the following calls of dfs, more and more pixels will get set, but the image created is never returned. That's why it stays zero in the calling code.

`labelCounter` is always 1. This should probably be incremented in the calling code to properly number the connected components.

Since you are only following `i-1` and `j-1`, some regions might not be detected as connected, even though they are. Additionally following `i+1` and `j+1` could help here.

From MATLAB: Use `set(0,'RecursionLimit',N)` to change the limit. Be aware that exceeding your available stack space can crash MATLAB and/or your computer.